# Div to show text in middle and darken text on hover

Tags: html, hover, effect

I found this neat code that darkens/tint the image on hover.

How can I add a text in the middle on hover?

```
.outerLink {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
img.darkableImage {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
img {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>  
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="outerLink">
        <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif" width="200" class="darkableImage" onmouseout="this.style.opacity = 1; this.filters.alpha.opacity = 100" onmouseover="this.style.opacity = 0.6; this.filters.alpha.opacity = 60" />
    </a>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/s1bsrj91/

Comment: I fail to see how the whole darkness thingy and all the pasted code has anything to do with showing a text on hover.

Comment: I want to have this type of effect: [link] (http://shop.samsonite.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-samsonite-Site/default/Default-Start?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=G_Samsonite%20Brand&gclid=CjwKEAjw-ZqrBRDt_KjhjcbzhhISJAAlRGvlZacVwp9IhG-cGqYvSewzo1Hp1x9dWPf_87Q361_uVRoCd2jw_wcB)

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to avoid adding javascript to markup, I would stick to using css for this.

https://jsfiddle.net/qz235wxy/69/

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.container:hover .text{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
         <img class='image' src="http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00342/114240651_cat_342943c.jpg" alt="cat">
         <span class='text'>CAT</span>
    </a>
</div>
```